# Sqlite create unique pair of columns

Tags: sqlite, unique

I want to create a table with two columns: `user_id`, `image_id`.
I don't want `user_id` or `image_id` to be unique, but I also want to protect my table from duplicate pairs of same `user_id` and `image_id`. Can I do that?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Add a separate constraint for both columns:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    user_id INTEGER,
    image_id INTEGER,
    [...],
    UNIQUE(user_id, image_id)
)
```

Comment: Adding that, UNIQUE constraint need to be at the end of the declaration of the columns.